# Javascript - Delay audio play

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, html5-audio

I'm playing an audio when a tooltip is visible, and the script works fine, but I can not find the way to a delay 2 secs the play...

```
$("#notify")[0].play(); 2000
```

What could be wrong?

Thanks in advance!

```js
if (total > 999 && total < 2999) {
  $('#regalo').show();

  if (localStorage.getItem('suppress_gift_tooltip_1') == null) {
    $('.tooltip').show();
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      $('.tooltip').fadeOut('slow');
    }, 6000);

    if (!$("#notify")[0].paused) { //audio
      $("#notify")[0].pause(); //audio
      $("#notify")[0].currentTime = 0; //audio
    } else { //audio
      setTimeout(function() { //audio
        $("#notify")[0].play();
         //audio   
      }, 2000)
    }; //audio

    localStorage.setItem('suppress_gift_tooltip_1', 'true')
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<audio id="notify">
      <source src="audio/notify.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
      <source src="audio/notify.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the javascript `setTimeout` to make this work. You are mis-placing the 2000. Place it after the function brackets (with a comma).

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function(){
      document.getElementById("notify").play(); /* or $("#notify").play() in jquery*/
      //console.log('two second delay!');
    }, 2000)
  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks **Rachel Gallen**, But it does not work, and a new script adds more load. I want to integrate the delay in my own script.

Comment: @Pablo_Web You already have a setTimeout in your script, but the syntax is wrong..

Comment: **Rachel**, Is that after `$ ("# notify") [0] .play ();` the script follows, and if I add `, 2000}` the entire script does not work... I do not know where to add the delay, and then close the script, the truth...

Comment: @Pablo_Web remove the 2000 from where it is currently and put the ', 2000' after the first curly bracket (' }') after it. There is no need for the [0] in your script

Comment: **Rachel** It does not work for me. I don't know the problem. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Pablo_Web I just put your code into a snippet. It gave an error 'total is not defined' - you haven't declared the total variable. That may be your problem (unless you have defined it but not posted it online). I moved the 2s delay in your snippet

Comment: @Pablo_Web it could also be a local storage error.... if you set a temp var in the snippet of var total =1000; you will see what I mean. Gives a 'document is sandboxed and lacks allow-same-origin flag ' error

Comment: **Rachel**, My post is a fragment of the original script (very large). Just do not worry, I solved it by modifying the audio files. Now they are 2 secs longer and the "bing" of my notification starts 2 secs later. It's not ideal, but it works for me. Thanks for you time, again. Regards!